# How to edit a register in normal mode from a script

Tags: register

I want to be able to write my own custom escape method.

If I want to paste the contents of register `s` while in insert mode, I can type `<C-R>s<CR>`.

If I want to escape all occurrences of `\`, I can type `<C-R>=escape(@s, '\')`.

How do I paste the contents of register `s` while executing an arbitrary formatting function?

---

Extra information:

The end goal is to be able to hit a key and append a function declaration from a `.c` file to a register. `void MyClass::foo() {` will turn into `void foo();`

I plan to solve this by writing an `=escape`-esque function that deletes words starting with capital letters, and does the equivalent of `:substitute/ *{$/;/`

Comment: Shameless plug: `lh#cpp#AnalysisLib_Function#AnalysePrototype('void MyClass::foo(int)')` (from my [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/)) will return `{'throw':[], 'parameters': [{'nl':0, 'name':'', 'type':'int', 'default':''}], 'constexpr':0, 'name':['MyClass', 'foo'], 'noexcept':'', 'const':0, 'return':'void', 'pure':0, 'qualifier':'', 'overriden':0, 'volatile':0, 'final':0, 'special_definition':''}`. From there you'll be able to reconstruct the declaration from the definition -- I usually use it the other way with `:GOTOIMPL` (virtual & co cannot be deduced from the definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define it all in one `substitute` all then replace the `escape`, since that can be any function. `<C-R>=substitute(@s, '\m\(\w\+\) \w\+::\([^{]\+\) {', '\1 \2;', '')<CR>`

If you don't want to do it all in one `substitute`, or to give it a descriptive name, you can write your own function.

For example:

```
function! FunctionDeclaration(snip)
  return substitute(a:snip, '\m\(\w\+\) \w\+::\([^{]\+\) {', '\1 \2;', '')
endfunction
```

Then invoke it with `<C-R>=FunctionDeclaration(@s)<CR>`

See `:help user-functions` for defining your own function like `FunctionDeclaration` above.

See `:help substitute()` for how to perform a regex substitution against a variable.

The breakdown of the regex suggested above:

- `\m` - Enable `magic` so that the regex behavior is not impacted by user settings. See `:help magic`.
- `\(\w\+\)` - Match a series of one or more "word characters". Matches the `void` in the example. See `:help \w`. Capture the result of that part of the match into the first match group. See `:help pattern-overview`. This can be referenced with `\1` in the replacement.
- `\w\+::` - Match a series of one or more "word characters" followed by `::`. This matches the `MyClass::` in the example. This is not matched in a subgroup so it will be dropped in the replacement.
- `\([^{]+\)` - Match a series of characters which are not `{` in a subgroup. This matches the `foo()` in the example. Can be reference by `\2` in the replacement.
- `{` - Match the literal `{` at the end. Not matched in a subgroup
  so it is dropped.

Comment: Excellent, so I can define a vimscript function of an arbitrary name and then plug in whatever logic I want. (Here's a link to a handy [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/vimscript), for anyone new to vimscript like myself). Your function is rad!! Thanks. I'm going to try and tailor it for myself to see how much functionality I can get into it. I will upvote when I get 15 rep

Comment: Added some references to the built-in help documentation in the answer. Note that `\m` at the start of the pattern has to do with `magic` (the syntax used for the pattern, which characters are escaped), not with multi-line regexes like it might in some other regex engines.